# setting up a S3 life cycle policy using script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scripting

When executing following command

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket krishna-s3auto --lifecycle-configuration '{"Rules":[{"Status":"Enabled","Prefix":"","Expiration":{"Days":'90'},"AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload":{"DaysAfterInitiation":'7'},"Transitions":[{"Days":'91'},"StorageClass":"STANDARD_IA"}],"ID":"Kittu"}]}'
```

I get the following error

> ```
> Error parsing parameter '--lifecycle-configuration': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' 
>   delimiter: line 1 column 168 (char 167)
> JSON received:
>   {"Rules":[{"Status":"Enabled","Prefix":"","Expiration":{"Days":90},
>    "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload":{"DaysAfterInitiation":7},
>    "Transitions":[{"Days":91},"StorageClass":"STANDARD_IA"}],"ID":"Kittu"}]}
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON was malformed and as well had errors like 'Transitions' keyword was used instead of 'Transition'

Following command should solve your problem

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket sas3auto --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

Following is what you need to put in the lifecycle.json file

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Prefix": "",
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 90
      },
      "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
        "DaysAfterInitiation": 7
      },
      "Transition": {
          "Days": 91,
          "StorageClass": "STANDARD_IA"
      },
      "ID": "Kittu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Arafat, I tried this and its working.. but if i want to give the values as variable how can i do that in Json.

Comment: for example i tried this and its working good. #!/bin/bash

days=$1
bucket_name=$2
echo 'days: $days'
echo 'bucket name: $bucket_name'
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket $bucket_name --lifecycle-configuration '{"Rules":[{"Status":"Enabled","Prefix":"","Expiration":{"Days":'$days'},"ID":"Kittu"}]}'

Comment: am running above mentioned script in ./s3lcyc.sh 91 s3auto

Comment: Hi @Ricky Vijay, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this though.